# Is it possible to add a method to a built-in type in Scala?

Tags: design-patterns, scala, infix-notation

I would like to add a method to a built-in type (e.g. Double), so that I can use an `infix` operator. Is that possible?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes and no.  Yes, you can make it *seem* like you have added a method to `double`.  For example:

```
class MyRichDouble(d: Double) {
  def <>(other: Double) = d != other
}

implicit def doubleToSyntax(d: Double) = new MyRichDouble(d)
```

This code adds the previously-unavailable `<>` operator to any object of type `Double`.  So long as the `doubleToSyntax` method is in scope so that it could be invoked without qualification, the following will work:

```
3.1415 <> 2.68     // => true
```

The "no" part of the answer comes from the fact that you aren't really adding anything to the `Double` class.  Instead, you are creating a conversion from `Double` to a new type which does define the method you want.  This can be a much more powerful technique than the open-classes offered by many dynamic languages.  It also happens to be completely type-safe.  :-)

Some limitations you should be aware of:

- This technique does not allow you to *remove* or *redefine* existing methods, just add new ones
- The implicit conversion method (in this case, `doubleToSyntax`) absolutely must be in-scope for the desired extension method to be available

Idiomatically, implicit conversions are either placed within singleton objects and imported (e.g. `import Predef._`) or within traits and inherited (e.g. `class MyStuff extends PredefTrait`).

Slight aside: "infix operators" in Scala are actually methods.  There is no magic associated with the `<>` method which allows it to be infix, the parser simply accepts it that way.  You can also use "regular methods" as infix operators if you like.  For example, the `Stream` class defines a `take` method which takes a single `Int` parameter and returns a new `Stream`.  This can be used in the following way:

```
val str: Stream[Int] = ...
val subStream = str take 5
```

The `str take 5` expression is literally identical to `str.take(5)`.

Comment: You can use the `implicit class` syntax to simplify this a little.

Answer (score 2):

This feature came in handy to implement a class performing error estimation:

```
object errorEstimation {
  class Estimate(val x: Double, val e: Double) {
    def + (that: Estimate) =
      new Estimate(this.x + that.x, this.e + that.e)
    def - (that: Estimate) =
      new Estimate(this.x - that.x, this.e + that.e)
    def * (that: Estimate) =
      new Estimate(this.x * that.x,
                   this.x.abs*that.e+that.x.abs*this.e+this.e*that.e)
    def / (that: Estimate) =
      new Estimate(this.x/that.x,
                   (this.x.abs*that.e+that.x.abs*this.e)/(that.x.abs*(that.x.abs-that.e)))
    def +- (e2: Double) =
      new Estimate(x,e+e2)
    override def toString =
      x + " +- " + e
  }
  implicit def double2estimate(x: Double): Estimate = new Estimate(x,0)
  implicit def int2estimate(x: Int): Estimate = new Estimate(x,0)

  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    println(((x: Estimate) => x+2*x+3*x*x)(1 +- 0.1))
    // 6.0 +- 0.93
    println(((x: Estimate) => (((y: Estimate) => y*y + 2)(x+x)))(1 +- 0.1))
    // 6.0 +- 0.84
    def poly(x: Estimate) = x+2*x+3/(x*x)
    println(poly(3.0 +- 0.1))
    // 9.33333 +- 0.3242352
    println(poly(30271.3 +- 0.0001))
    // 90813.9 +- 0.0003
    println(((x: Estimate) => poly(x*x))(3 +- 1.0))
    // 27.037 +- 20.931
  }
}
```

Comment: That's actually kinda neat. :)